# How would I write a RewriteRule to make an exception for one file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have this in my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ index.php?pagename=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

The the html file name is rewritten to the pagename query string.

However I'm trying to allow access to one particular static html file, so somehow I need to overwrite the rule or make an exception.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. No point appending `QUERY_STRING` yourself; you'll leave a stray `&` if there isn't any, and mod_rewrite already has a tool to do it better:

   `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ index.php?pagename=$1 [QSA]`
2. You can control a `RewriteRule` with a `RewriteCond` that precedes it. For example:

   `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/staticpage.html$`
   `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ index.php?pagename=$1 [QSA]`
3. Another useful pattern is `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` which will bypass the following `RewriteRule` *any* time that the URL would have matched an existing regular file in the docroot.